# How to evaluate these types of integrals in a shorter way?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question.**

> How to evaluate
> $$
> I = \int\frac{x^{5}}{x-1}\,dx?
> $$

First of all, let me tell that this integral is very easy, but still I am asking about this integral because I want an alternative solution to this integral.

Basically to integrate this above expression we have to substitute $(x-1)=u$ so $dx=du$ and $x=(u+1)$. Therefore, we can write this above integral as:
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int\frac{x^{5}}{x-1}\,dx \\
&= \int\frac{(u+1)^{5}}{u}\,du \\
&= \int\frac{u^{5}+5u^{4}+10u^{3}+10u^{2}+5u+1}{u}\,du \\
&= \int\Bigl(u^{4}+5u^{3}+10u^{2}+10u+5+\frac{1}{u}\Bigr)\,du. 
\end{align}
$$
Now after this step we can easily integrate this above expression.

---

**My doubt.**

Is there any other way to integrate this above expression without writing the binomial expansion of $(1+u)^{5}$? For e.g. here in this integral since the highest power of $x$ is $5$ so it is easy to integrate after writing the binomial expansion. But if this question was

Integrate
$$
I = \int\frac{x^{15}}{x-1}\,dx,
$$
then it would have been very tough to integrate by writing the binomial expansion of $(1+u)^{15}$ after substituting $(x-1)=u$. So, I want to know whether there is any shortcut tricks to evaluate these types of integrals.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x^k}{x-1}=\frac{x^k-1+1}{x-1}=\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-1}=\underbrace{(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}+\dotsb+1)}_{\text{geo. series}}+\frac{1}{x-1}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the hint by @AnuragA in the comments, a rational function can always be rewritten as the sum of a polynomial (quotient) and a proper fraction (from the remainder) using the [polynomial division algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polynomial_long_division).

> Given polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x) \neq 0$, there are unique polynomials $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ such that
> $$
> A(x) = Q(x)\cdot B(x) + R(x)
> $$
> and either $R(x) = 0$ or $\deg R(x) < \deg B(x)$.

As a consequence, we can rewrite
$$
\frac{A(x)}{B(x)} = Q(x) + \frac{R(x)}{B(x)}.
$$

Why is this "better" for integration? Obviously, $Q(x)$ is a polynomial, so that's nice. But when we look at degrees, the remaining rational term is a *proper* fraction, so it will be easier to deal with in general. If the denominator factors, then [partial fraction decomposition](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Partial_fraction_decomposition) can be applied to it.

Moreover, since $\deg R(x) < \deg B(x)$, the remainder fraction $\smash{\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}}$ term tends to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, so that asymptotically, the original rational function behaves like the polynomial $Q(x)$. This describes all the types of asymptotes (horizontal, "slant" i.e. linear, and otherwise).

---

In your example (and its generalization), since $B(x) = x - 1$ is linear (degree $1$), the remainder has to be constant (degree $0$), which means that the antiderivative will just consist of polynomial terms together with a single logarithm term.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out with this question